# Suppose that $ABCD$ is a trapezoid with $AB$ parallel to $CD$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that $ABCD$ is a trapezoid with $AB$ parallel to $CD$. Let $P$ be the point where the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect. Show that the triangles $CDP$ and $ABP$ are similar. Use this to prove that the diagonals of a trapezoid cut each other into segments that are proportional to the parallel sides of the trapezoid.

I am having trouble showing that $CDP$ and $ABP$ are similar. Also, i am not sure where to start with showing the diagonals of a trapezoid cut each other into segments that are proportional to the parallel sides of the trapezoid. Here is what I have gotten so far

$\textbf{Attempt:}$

If two triangle are similar than it follows that one triangle must be a scaler of the other triangle. This can be shown by establishing linear dependence. Recall from linear algebra that a system is linearly dependent when the determinant is equal to zero. Therefore, see that
\begin{align*}
\det\begin{pmatrix} 
  a    & d & 1\\ 
  b & c & 1\\
  p&p&1
\end{pmatrix}=0&\Rightarrow\det\begin{pmatrix} 
 a     & d&1\\ 
 b-a&c-d&0\\
 p-a&p-d&0
\end{pmatrix}=0\\
&\Rightarrow(b-a)(p-d)-(p-d)(c-d)=0\\
&\Rightarrow(b-a)(p-d)=(p-d)(c-d)\\
&\Rightarrow\dfrac{|p-a|}{|b-a|}=\dfrac{|p-d|}{|c-d|}\\
&\Rightarrow\dfrac{|PA|}{|BA|}=\dfrac{|PD|}{|CD|}
\end{align*}
We must now show this holds for our given triangles. . . I have tried using sine law for this but it doesn't seem to work. Any nudges in the right direction are much appreciated.

Comment: Two triangles are similar if they have the same angles; that is, $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$ are similar if $(\angle A,\angle B,\angle C)$ is a permutation (rearrangement) of $(\angle A', \angle B', \angle C')$.

Comment: For instance, $\angle APB = \angle CPD$, because they are the opposite angles from where two lines intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my hint, here's the proof. (Don't peek, Jeremy, until you've read my hint.)

$\angle APB=\angle CPD$, because they're a pair of vertical angles (opposing angles formed when two lines intersect). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Vertical_and_adjacent_angle_pairs

Also, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are parallel lines cut by a transversal $L_3$ (a line not parallel to $L_1$), then the alternate interior angles are equal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(geometry)#Alternate_angles

Applying this fact to the lines $AB$ and $CD$, as cut by the transversal $BD$, $\angle ABP=\angle CDP$. Applying this fact to the same parallel lines cut by $AC$, $\angle PAB = \angle PCD$.

Hence $(\angle APB,\angle ABP, \angle PAB)=(\angle CPD, \angle CDP, \angle PCD)$, making the triangles $APB$ and $CPD$ similar. QED. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similar_triangles

Comment: So, I see what you did there, and thank you, but I don't understand what is meant by "Use this to prove that the diagonals of a trapezoid cut each other into segments that are proportional to the parallel sides of the trapezoid." Is this asking me to show that the side lengths $DP=PC=DC$. As well show that the side lengths $AP=PB=AB$. Moreover, if this what the question is asking would I use sine law since the first part was built on angles being equal?

Comment: You're not being asked to prove $DP=PC=DC$, because it might not be true. Once you know that triangles $APB$ and $CPD$ are similar, then you know that the *ratios of corresponding sides* are equal to each other; that is $${AP \over CP} = {PB \over PD} = {AB \over CD}.$$